# iOS version Xamarin app compatibility

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am building an app for iOS using Xamarin Studio on mac and have set the Deployment target to 7.0 but was not able to test on a iOS 7.0 , so my questing is will my app be supported on the devices running iOS 7.0 and above or is there any other or higher versions I have to specify,

I am able to run the app on a simulator with iOS 10.3.1 now for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what UI you want to use. If you want to use Xamarin.Forms then the answer is: no you cant use Xamarin.Forms on iOS 7. It requires at least iOS 8 to do so (see: [Xamarin.Forms Requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Target_Platforms).

If you're using platform-specific UI projects you should be able to target iOS 7 generally. You might run into problems with newer version of XCode though so be prepared to download and install an older version of XCode side-by-side with the latest version. That's what we are doing on our build machine(s) too.
If you want to publish to the AppStore also make sure to provide a 64bit version of your app or else you won't be able to successfully submit.

Also I would recommend to change to the new Visual Studio Version 15.3 as this one has built-in C# 7.1 Support now. Also Xamarin Studio won't receive any updates in the future anymore so it's very likely that with the next Xamarin release something will break and you won't be able to develop your app further.

Comment: I am developing platform-specific UI projects and Visual Studio 2017 latest Version on Mac @MarcelDutt